# MySQL- How to get values using Group By

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------------+--------+-------+
| Date(yyyy-mm-dd)| name   | price |
+-----------------+--------+-------+
|    2021-03-01   | APPLE  |    15 |
|    2021-03-01   | Orange |    10 |
|    2021-03-01   | Banana |     5 |
|    2021-03-02   | Apple  |    16 |
|    2021-03-02   | Orange |     9 |
|    2021-03-02   | Banana |     4 |
|    2021-03-03   | Apple  |    17 |
|    2021-03-03   | Orange |    11 |
|    2021-03-03   | Banana |     5 |
+-----------------+--------+-------+



    **Fruit Value**
```

I'm trying to get names of fruit whose price increasing everyday for all days. So output should be "**Apple**", as Apple's price is on 1st march is 15, on 2nd march it is 16, and 3rd march it is 17...I tried to solve this problem using group by, but still I'm not able to solve it... Please anyone give me suggestions.

Comment: @JanezKuhar Thanks for your suggestion, surely I will try and let you know.

Comment: @JanezKuhar can you please tell me how to filter monotonically increasing groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have prices for all fruits for all dates then you can do it with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT name
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT price) -- all prices are different
   AND GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY Date) = GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price)
   -- prices ordered by date are in the same order as prices ordered ascending by price
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c66bf9d4b417a5590fc0e81775d28199).